# HashMap and smooks

Tags: xml, smooks

I need to transform a Map into xml, and then using smooks convert it back into a Map.
This map can contain complex values (ex: List), How to achieve that using smooks?
ex:

```
<m:map>
<entry key="a"> <l:list> <a>a1</a> <a>a2</a> </l:list></entry>
<entry key="b"> <l:list> <b>b1</b> <b>b2</b> </l:list></entry>
</m:map>
```

where `<a>` and `<b>` tags are referring to existing A and B models

```
class A { String property; }
class B { String property; }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with smooks and groovy:

```
 <jb:bean beanId="inputValue" class="java.util.HashMap" createOnElement="StartElement">
        <jb:value property="prop"          data="StartElement/SomeValue/AnotherValue" />
    </jb:bean>


<g:groovy executeOnElement="StartElement">
         <g:imports>

        </g:imports>
        <g:script>
        <![CDATA[           
                //code for setting the objects                              

        ]]>
        </g:script>
    </g:groovy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<jb:bean beanId="itemList" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="Element">
     <jb:wiring beanIdRef="item" />
</jb:bean>
```